# Apply Django permissions based on Request and Model

Tags: django, django-users, django-permissions

**TL;DR;**

Is there anyway in Django, to **automatically** check the permissions of a User/Request against default permissions (add,change,view,delete) before executing a query?

---

I'm pretty new to Django and what I'm trying to achieve is utilizing  Django's permissions in my apps without actually writing code for each view/request(post/...). I have a lot of groups with a veracity of permissions associated with them and it's really hard to check every and each one of these permissions.

Let's say I've got a model named `Article` and a group named `readers` with only one permission: `article.read_article`; And there is a form on the home page which can be used to add new articles.

Is there any way to stop the users in the `reader` group from adding new articles using this form without actually writing code for it? For example, based on Request, Group, Permissions, and Models involved. Or write something in the model to check all necessary permissions before executing a query.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can achieve it.

1. In your template display the forms only to user that has permission to create article.
2. Create a pre-save [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/) handler. Get reference to current user. Check permission of the user. If user does not have permission raise exception. Raising exception will prevent the saving of the record.

Comment: I know that. I just don't want to touch the views in any form. I want to left this to models (Based on this request (User) Should I execute this query or not). And I've got lots of custom permissions. It really doesn't answers my question. Thank you though :)

Comment: @Ravexina you mean while saving the record, permission check is to be done?

Comment: Depending on the query, at least the basic permissions check should happen automatically (add,change,view,delete). That's what I'm looking for. I'm not sure if it's even possible. Just curious.

Comment: @Ravexina you can use pre_save signals.

Comment: @Ravexina It is possible. you can use pre_save signals. You need to get a reference of user in your signal handler. And in the handler you can check if the users have permission.